# Conditional API Fetching using ReactApp Javascript

Tags: reactjs

I need some help with my code where it has to display the API data when the condition is the following

1. use componentWillReceiveProps()
2. when count == 2 it will fetch api

```js
    import React, {useState, useEffect,Component} from "react";

    var x = 2;
    const App =() => {
      const [hasError, setErrors]= useState(false)
      const [apps, setApps] = useState ("Loading");

      useEffect(()=>{
      async function fetchData(){
        const res = await fetch ("https://m2dzass19b.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/vdrOptimize/21-09-2019");
        res
          .json()
          .then(res => setApps(res))
          .catch(err => setErrors(err))
      }

        fetchData();
      } );

          return(
            <div>
            <span>{JSON.stringify(apps)}</span>
            <hr/>
            </div>
          );
        }
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: I need to add componentWillReceiveProps() and only display when the count is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here's the solution

Change your useEffect as this

```
useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://m2dzass19b.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/vdrOptimize/21-09-2019"
  );
  res
    .json()
    .then(res => setApps(res))
    .catch(err => setErrors(err));
}
if (props.id === 2) {
  fetchData();
}
}, [props.id]);
```

Hope it helps

UPDATE: This is how you can do it using comonentWillReceiveProps

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://m2dzass19b.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/vdrOptimize/21-09-2019"
  );
  res
    .json()
    .then(res => this.setState({ apps: res }))
    .catch(err => this.setState({ hasError: err }));
}
if (nextProps.id === 2) {
  fetchData.call(this);
}
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hawking-wk91d)

Note: componentWillReceiveProps() is deprecated lifecycle method

Comment: Thank you but is it possible to add componentWillReceiveProps() in the code

Comment: aren't you using hooks ?

Comment: ok to use componentWillReceiveProps you need to convert your functional component to class component

Comment: Hi im not using hooks. I need to use class components. Is it possible to help

Comment: @PriyaS i have updated answer for componentWillReceiveProps(),

Comment: Thank you. It shows Line 9:  'componentWillReceiveProps' is not defined  no-undef
any idea how to fix this?

Comment: no problem, if it helped you feel free to accept and up vote the answer, cheers

Comment: @PriyaS did it help you ?

Comment: @PriyaS if it helped you please accept and up vote the answer, cheers